# Yahoo finance Historical Daily data to mysql daily

Tags: php, mysql

Another Yahoo Finance question.

I need a php function that will check if the DB is up-to-date (meaning there is no new info to download) & if not download the needed info ( I can already do this part).

What I have already:

I can download the info manually.  When I say manually, I mean I can download it by going at the end of the day & calling my script "manually".  So, I don't need help with that.

What I need help with is:

```
//Checking if the DB is up-to-date & if not, then update it
```

If it helps, I will call the function from a checkbox in an html form that will have the checkbox update DB.  It's done this way, because it resides on a local box & will not be online all the time.

However, if it is easier to simply host it & do it via cron job, that is a consideration as well.

Answer (score 0):

What determines if the db is up to date? If its the time of the last update, then you need to store the time of the last update somewhere, and then check it. If its the data itself, then you need to download the data to check.

setting up a cron job, or scheduled task, seems to be a separate concern.

Comment: The DB `information_schema UPDATE_TIME` variable from a mysql query is what is used to check the last update.  There are 100 tickers to check, so I figured using the `UPDATE_TIME` from the `data` table would be simplest.  The way yahoo finance works, you have to build the url with the date & I didn't see a reason to download unnecessarily.